# Preserve style of clicked link

Tags: html, css

I have this list of links, they get called using php. If they get clicked the page refreshes to load the content of the link, however I would like the link to stay the same style as ( `:hover`. )

The link looks something like this:

```
<a href="editfiles.php?file=pages/something.html">something.html</a>
```

The css for it is:

```
a:hover{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #039AD2;
}

a {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

I'm not sure how I could be able to achieve that.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you mean that already visited links should look like *hovered* links?

Comment: probably this help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: No, currently active tab should look like hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You should reorganize your css like this:

```
a {
    color: #777;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #039AD2;
}
```

than already visited links and also currently active links will look like the hovered links.

Comment: The thing is that the page gets reloaded and it doesn’t know on which page it actually is.

Comment: than you have to use server side code for rendering or javascript on the client side